# How to change background image on click?

Tags: jquery, css

I have few lines of jquery to replace the default text on click. How to change the default image as well? Pls suggest a better way to do this. Thanks in advance!
    [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajd4rq8q/).

> ```
> <div class="wrap">
>   <span tabindex="1" class="default">videos</span>
>   <ul class="filter">
>     <li class="vid">
>       <a href="#">Videos</a>
>     </li>
>     <li class="pho">
>       <a href="#">Photos</a>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? and which image you want to change?

Comment: I can't see any code related to changing an image in the CodePen you've provided.

Comment: `targetElement.css('background-image','url(yourImage.jpg)');`

Comment: Your CodePen seems to not completed.

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with it for 2 hrs :(

Comment: @user3892090 Please take a look at the answer I posted in answer section. I have not made any changes in css code but jQuery code. It is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have image classes, all you need is to add them to `.default` span. Just a little CSS adjustment is needed:

```
.wrap span.default, ul.filter li {
    background: #333 url(http://funr.net/play/spr.png) no-repeat 5px 5px;
}
.filter li.vid, .wrap span.default.vid {
    background-position: 5px 5px;
}
.filter li.pho, .wrap span.default.pho {
    background-position: 5px -17px;
}
```

Now simply add class name to `default` span:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.filter li').click(function () {
        $('.wrap').find('.default').text($(this).text())
                  .attr('class', 'default ' + this.className);
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94xLh0ct/

Comment: Hi sir, thanks a lot! This is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the position of the image. You are having a sprite and you need to change the position of the image upon click.

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/fwgLt2f0/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.filter li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.wrap').find('.default').text($(this).text()).css("background-position", $(this).css("background-position"));
    });
});
```

You need to adjust the css as in the example and modify it further to make everything pixel perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.filter li').click(function() {
$('.wrap').find('.default').text($(this).text());

   var cssBgPos= $(this).css('background-position'); 
   $('.wrap').find('.default').css('cssText', 'background-position:'+cssBgPos+'!important');

});
});
```

Working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/s4ut0yc4/

Answer (score 0):

Following this template, add which element you wish to change and the relevant url of the image to change it to.

```
$('#yourElement').css('background-image','url(image.jpg)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using sprites, you need to change the background-position.

Something like this (not tested):

```
    if ($(this).hasClass('pho')) {
       $('default').css('background-position', '5px -17px');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vid') {
       $('default').css('background-position', '0 0');
    }
```